# Adventureworks dbo.SalesOrderDetail 'PK_Sales.SalesOrderDetail' is not a constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, adventureworks

I am creating own portfolio project based on AdventureWOrks 2017 database.Project is code first from database. I have a concrete problem with this table dbo.SalesOrderDetail . When start to insert a new record/ or update-database migration, it throws me an exception:

> 'PK_Sales.SalesOrderDetail' is not a constraint.

I found an article with explаnation [enter link description here](https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/entity-framework-working-with-an-existing-database/#1-2-fixing-a-problem-with-how-the-two-keys-are-defined-in-salesorderdetail-table) but it doesn't work. When I remove annotations it throws me another exception:

> {"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'SalesOrderDetail' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF."}

```
[Key]
[Column(Order = 0)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int SalesOrderID { get; set; }

[Key]
[Column(Order = 1)]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int SalesOrderDetailID { get; set; }
```

Where do I wrong?

Comment: If it's "Code First From an Existing Database" there should be no migrations.

Comment: Thank you! It works, finally